# backbone.js this.[method] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm having an issue with a helper function inside my Backbon.js View.  When it's run, it dies with the following error message about the first line of the "addCalc" function:

> TypeError: this.getCalcValue is not a function

It's really puzzling because in the "initialize" function defined just above, all the functions seem to be defined.  It feels like I'm calling the sibling method wrong, and the "initialize" method is an exception where "this" can be used to reference the object.

Is there something wrong/missing with the following code, or something I missed with the backbone documentation?

```
CalcView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#calcView"),
    initialize: function () {
        this.resetCalc();
    },

    addCalc: function (model) {
        var cost = this.getCalcValue(model.get('currentCost'));
        var custom = this.getCalcValue(model.get('customProgram'));

        var variables = { id: model.get('id'),
                category: model.get('category'),
                shortDesc: model.get('shortDescription'),
                description: model.get('description'),
                currentCost: cost,
                customProgram: custom,
        };

        var template = _.template($('#calc_template').html(), variables);
        $("#calc_payload").append(template);
    },

    resetCalc: function(models) {
        $("#calc_payload tr").remove();
    },

    removeCalc: function(model){
        $("#calc_payload #" + model.get('id')).remove();
    },

    updateCalcs: function(model) {

        var cost = model.get('currentCost');
        var custom = model.get('customProgram');

        $("#" + model.get("id") + " .currentCost").text(this.getCalcValue(cost));
        $("#" + model.get("id") + " .customProgram").text(this.getCalcValue(custom));

        /*var currentCostSum = 0;
        var customProgramSum = 0;
        $("#calc_payload .currentCost").each(function() {
            var temp = Number(($(this).text()).replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));
            if (!isNaN(temp))
                    currentCostSum += temp;
        });

        $("#calc_payload .customProgram").each(function() {
            var temp = Number(($(this).text()).replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));
            if (!isNaN(temp))
                customProgramSum += temp;
        });

        $("#calc_footer .currentCost").text("$" + ((currentCostSum == 0) ? " -- " : CurrencyFormatted(currentCostSum.toFixed(2))));
        $("#calc_footer .customProgram").text("$" + ((customProgramSum == 0) ? " -- " : CurrencyFormatted(customProgramSum.toFixed(2))));*/
    },

    getCalcValue: function(value) {
        if (typeof value == 'string' || value instanceof String)
            return value.toString();
        else if (isNaN(value))
            return "$ -- ";
        else
            return "$" + value.toFixed(2); 
    },                  
});
```

The code that executes the "addCalc" function is driven by a backbone collection.  Basically, when the collection is added to, the CalcView.addCalc is called

```
Calculations = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Calculation,
    //This is our Friends collection and holds our Friend models
    initialize: function (models, options) {
        this.on("add", options.onAdd);
        this.on("remove", options.onRemove);
        this.on("reset", options.onReset);
        //Listen for new additions to the collection and call a view function if so
    }
});


//This is where addCalc is used.
var calcview = new CalcView();
var calc_collection = new Calculations( null, { 
    onAdd: calcview.addCalc, 
    onRemove: calcview.removeCalc, 
    onReset: calcview.resetCalc 
});
```

Comment: Please post the code which invokes `addCalc` function.

Comment: I updated the post with the piece that calls the addCalc method

Comment: how are your events bound?

Comment: Digging around, I see now that "this" is currently bound to the collection object that is calling the "addCalc" method when an element is added to the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `initialize` function add this line of code:

```
_.bindAll(this,'addCalc');
```

This will bind `this` to be your `CalcView` for the `addCalc` function. You can put multiple comma separated method names in there if you need to bind more than one function...

See [Underscore's documentation on it here.](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll)

Answer (score 0):

When you bind events on `collection` you can send the `context` as third argument. Try sending one more option property as your `calcview` and pass it as context.

```
this.on("add", options.onAdd, options.calcview);
this.on("remove", options.onRemove, options.calcview);
this.on("reset", options.onReset, options.calcview);
```